# Plot lines using different styles without a data file

Tags: gnuplot

The following code creates a plot. My question is: how can one create those two lines using different styles without putting them in a data file and using `plot 'plotting_data.dat' index 0 with linespoints linestyle 1, '' index 1 with linespoints linestyle 2`

```
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5
set style line 2 \
    linecolor rgb '#dd181f' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 5 pointsize 1.5

# THIS WON'T WORK
# plot '-' index 0 with linespoints linestyle 1, \
#      '-' index 1 with linespoints linestyle 2

# THIS CREATES A PLOT
plot '-' with linespoints linestyle 1
# First data block (index 0)
# X   Y
  1   2
  2   3


# Second index block (index 1)
# X   Y
  3   2
  4   1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify if you absolutely need to plot your data via `'-'`.
If you want two plots with data via `'-'` you have to provide the data twice. Check `help data`.

There is another way to "deliver" data together with the gnuplot code by defining datablocks. Check `help datablocks`.

```
### data in code included
reset session

set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5
set style line 2 \
    linecolor rgb '#dd181f' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 5 pointsize 1.5

$Data <<EOD
# First data block (index 0)
# X   Y
  1   2
  2   3


# Second index block (index 1)
# X   Y
  3   2
  4   1
EOD

plot $Data index 0 with linespoints linestyle 1, \
     $Data index 1 with linespoints linestyle 2
### end of code
```